# set the caller language ( Field ) when initiating the call in Zendesk

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-sdk

I want to set the Language field in the ticket to one of available custom field values - (English , French, Spanish, German) when the user calls. For example if I use this js code on the frontend of my website to initialize the web widget

```
zE("messenger:set", "conversationFields", [{ id: '8426045896463', value: 'german'}])
```

it should have pre-selected the german from the dropdown when the agen views the ticket

[image]